# What is this fragrant purple flower, found in California?

Tags: identification, flowers

I spotted this in San Francisco, CA. It seems to have a mild and pleasant fragrance all year round.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for telling us where you live, and for posting a nice picture of that pretty flower! It really helps with identification. If people ask for more information, you can [edit] it right into the question. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a Lantana, probably [Lantana montevidensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana_montevidensis) there a lots of varieties, the exact one I could not say.